# aspose word table set BackgroundPatternColor

Tags: c#, aspose.words

I have an existing table in Aspose Words template, I want to change the Background Pattern color inside the row. How can I achieve it?

```
public static void SetColor(ref Table table)
{
    Row row =table.Rows[1];
}
```

Comment: have you looked at the [Aspose Word Documentation](https://docs.aspose.com/display/cellsnet/Changing+the+Font+and+Color+of+a+Cell) you could have just done a google search..

Comment: i don't work with builder!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public static void SetColor(ref Table table)
{
     Row t = table.Rows[1];
     foreach (Cell c in t.GetChildNodes(NodeType.Cell, true))
     {
          c.CellFormat.Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = Color.FromArgb(198, 217, 241);
     }
}
```

Comment: delete this and add it to your original question, click the `edit` link directly under the original question you posted